# send sms without any prompt and read the received sms

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air-native-extension

I'm creating app using flash cs 6. I need to send sms from my app. I created the native extension which will send the sms. It uses default sms manager.It is working fine. But when i use it to send sms it prompt me a message that it may cause charges on your mobile account. Is there a way to send sms without that message ? I heard some app ask if the app can send sms or not at the beginning of the installation. And when user agree to send sms from app, app never promt that message. Is there a way to do that ? And I also want the app to read the sms that send from me.

I used following code for sending sms:

```
 SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
 smsManager.sendTextMessage(recipient, null, text, null, null);
```

Now I also can read sms using following code:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
Cursor c= context.getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null ,null,null); 
c.moveToFirst();  

String body = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString();
c.close();
```

Is there a way to receive the sms in app when the device first receive the sms? I want to read the sms send from me/server only.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look into the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

To receive an SMS when it arrives at the device you need to setup a receiver and add the SMS_RECEIVED intent filter:

```
<receiver android:name="YourSMSReceiverClass" android:exported="true" > 
    <intent-filter android:priority="1000"> 
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

In your receiver you can then process the SMS for your needs:

```
public static final String SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
public static final String SMS_EXTRA_NAME = "pdus";

@Override
public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent ) 
{
    if (SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) 
    {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if ( extras != null )
        {
            Object[] smsExtra = (Object[]) extras.get( SMS_EXTRA_NAME );

            for ( int i = 0; i < smsExtra.length; ++i )
            {
                SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])smsExtra[i]);

                String message = sms.getMessageBody().toString();
                String address = sms.getOriginatingAddress();

                // Here you can add any your code to work with incoming SMS
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also in your receiver you can stop the SMS from being put to incoming by calling:

```
this.abortBroadcast();
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I'm using native extension. I really don't know how to setup receiver in Native extension. As I understand, when using extension, flash call a function to java and it calls only once. If I setup receiver function will it wait for the incoming sms continously or should i call that function from flash again ? And I also like to know if it is possible to cancel the sending sms process if it took too long ?

Comment: You define receivers the same as in a native application. You add a class into your native extension library and implement a BroadcastReceiver then pass the class name into the receiver just as normal. The only thing you have to do is make the native to as3 communications work, which you can do via a static reference to your FREContext.

Comment: I forgot to mention you add the receiver in your manifest additions of your AIR application descriptor!